# Converting textBox value to integer

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a `textBox` entry into an integer value so it can be used in an equation.
When I try create the `int` value using

```
 int number1 = int.Parse(num1.Text);
```

I get an error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Tutorial_Form.Form1.num1'

Comment: where do you have this statement of code?

Comment: You can use int number1=convert.Toint(num1.text);

Comment: Are you putting this inside a method or a class declaration(it wont work here) ? Also you can try  Convert.ToInt32()

Comment: You'd need to move this to the constructor body in order to do it as part of initialization. It's hard to tell what you're trying to do from just a single line of code though. More context would really help.

Comment: @JonSkeet I suspect he actually meant to put this in a `Click` event (or something like that), putting it in the constructor would accomplish the same thing as this field initializer would, but that would be pretty useless, since the textbox would just have been created. Just for the record.

Comment: Side note: instead of "searched alot"/"tried alot" text in your question please show links to questions/articles you've found and code you've tried. It will make helping you much easier.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: Possibly. It's hard to tell. But the textbox could have been created with some existing text...

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, yeah, no, I'm definitely not disagreeing with what you said. There's not enough information to know what's truly going on. I was just adding on to that, saying that what it looks like is happening is probably not what he *meant* to do. But certainly, we need to see more code to draw any conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to put the code to set that field in a method.

Does it really make sense to initialise a field using the contents of a `TextBox` though?  The user can't possibly have entered anything into the control, so there's no integer to parse.  You need to consider when it is that you want to get the number from the input and put your code there, e.g. the `Click` event handler of a `Button`.